# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (l5 remote sample app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I get the error above when I am trying to run the unaltered sample application of the L5 Remote (http://www.l5remote.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=14).

See the screenshot attached[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have not correctly linked `libL5Backend` to your target.

Add it to your target's "Link Binary with Libraries" section under the Build Phases tab in the target settings. In the image shown below, the `+` icon will let you add the library to the target.

You could also remove the warnings by reviewing the "Library Search Path" setting (under Build Settings) and make sure it does not contain wrong paths.

[image]